# create an array of pipe in c

Tags: c, pipe

I'm new to `C` and I was trying to make an `array` of `pipe` but it's giving me an error.
This is what I was trying to do :

```
int fd[N][2];
pipe(fd);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What does `pipe[fd];` mean?

Comment: and what error is it giving

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a `for loop` like this:

```
int fd[N][2];
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    pipe(fd[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for `pipe` is, according the documentation,

```
int pipe(int fildes[2]);
```

That is, the argument is a length two array of `int`s.  However, in your example, `fd` is not an array of `int`s but an array of arrays of `int`s.  You need to call `pipe` on the elements of `fd` individually.